# Unexpected keyword argument when using **kwargs in constructor

Tags: python

I'm baffled.  I'm trying to make a subclass that doesn't care about any keyword parameters -- just passes them all along as is to the superclass, and explicitly sets the one parameter that is required for the constructor.  Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
class BaseClass(object):
    def __init__(self, required, optional=None):
        pass

def SubClass(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SubClass, self).__init__(None, **kwargs)

a = SubClass(optional='foo')  # this throws TypeError!?!??
```

This fails with

```
leo@loki$ python minimal.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "minimal.py", line 9, in <module>
    a = SubClass(optional='foo')
TypeError: SubClass() got an unexpected keyword argument 'optional'
```

How can it complain about an unexpected keyword argument when the method has `**kwargs`?

(Python 2.7.3 on Ubuntu)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
def SubClass(BaseClass):
```

is a function, not a class. There's no error because `BaseClass` could be an argument name, and nested functions are allowed. Syntax is fun, isn't it?

```
class SubClass(BaseClass):
```

Answer (score 2):

Stumbled on to this post when searching for an answer to the exact same error, but different cause.

I worked out my problem (python beginners mistake), but thought I should put it up here in case it helps someone else.

My project structure:

```
project\
--package1\
----Module1.py
----Module2.py
--package2\
...blah blah blah...
```

**where Module2 extends Module1, and class names were the same as the module/file names**

In Module2.py, I had:

```
from package1 import Module1
```

assuming that this would import the classes within.

Received an unexpected keyword argument error when I tried to create Module2 Class

```
Mod2 = Module2(kw1=var1, kw2=var2)
```

Fixed by using

```
from package1.Module1 import Module1
```

That is `[package name].[module name] import [class name]`

Hope this helps someone else out there